# CSS Смена цвета шрифта в зависимости от фона подкладки

Tags: css, css3

Есть ли возможность менять цвет на определенный в зависимости от того какой фон под текстом. Приведу пример.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

b {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  font-size: 10em;
}

.animation_mode {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation: 2s ease-in 1s infinite move;
  background-color: #2F3138;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes move {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translateX(-230%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="steps_list">
  <b>Test</b>
  <b>Test</b>
</div>

<div class="animation_mode"></div>
```

Возможно ли менять цвет шрифта определенных букв на белый (постепенное закрашивание), когда под ними фоновое изображение ?  *Только определенных букв, которые перекрываются. Изображения и слова пренадлежат разным элементам.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;

    --bkg: black;
    --white: gold;

    background-color: red;
    
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.title h1 {
    font-size: 25vmin;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    color: black;
}

.anima {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    

    transform: translateX(100em) rotateZ(-90deg);
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.9;
    mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
    animation: Move 4s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes Move {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(30em) ;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-35em) ;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="title">
        <h1>ЖабаСкрипт</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="anima">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

можно поиграться с  mix-blend-mode: если вас этот вариант устроит

Comment: Пробовал, но не получилось.  Фоновое изображение четко `#2F3138;` а цвет текста должен поменяться на `#fff;` А смена цвена текста с черного на белый как-то не происходит.

Comment: вот посмотри это https://codepen.io/TajShireen/pen/xxGPEEp

Comment: Спасибо, К сожалению данный вариант тоже не понятно как применить к данной задачи.